# Timing of lambda expression move capture

Tags: c++, c++14, sequence, undefined-behavior, evaluation

When I use Boost.Asio, creating object such as `ip::tcp::socket` or `deadline_timer` as `std::shared_ptr` and copy captured it to the completion handler as lambda expression.

I curious that what happens if I use move capture instead of copy capture. I think that it is dangerous. In the following example, I think that `tim = std::move(tim)` is evaluated before `tim->async_wait`. So tim no longer has valid pointer. It is my guess. In order to trace `std::shared_ptr`'s behavior, I created `std::shared_ptr` wrapper `shared_ptr`.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

namespace as = boost::asio;

template <typename... Args>
struct shared_ptr : std::shared_ptr<Args...> {
    using base = std::shared_ptr<Args...>;
    using base::base; // inheriting constructor

    shared_ptr(shared_ptr&& other) : base(std::move(other)) {
        std::cout << "move" << std::endl;
    }
    typename base::element_type* operator->() {
        std::cout << "->" << std::endl;
        return base::get();
    }
};

int main() {
    as::io_context ioc;

    ioc.post( 
        [&] {
            shared_ptr<as::deadline_timer> tim(new as::deadline_timer(ioc));
            tim->expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
            tim->async_wait( 
                // I think that it is dangerous because tim has been moved before tim->async_wait()
                [&, tim = std::move(tim)] 
                    std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl;
                }
            );
        }
    );

    ioc.run();
}
```

I run the code on several environment:

All option is `-std=c++14`

g++ 7.1.0 or later : https://wandbox.org/permlink/rgJLp66vH7jKodQ8  A

g++ 6.3.0 : https://wandbox.org/permlink/XTIBhjJSqmkQHN4P  B

clang++ 4.0.1~ : https://wandbox.org/permlink/nEZpFV874pKstjHA A

**Output A**

```
->
->
move
move
move
move
Success
```

**Output B**

```
->
move
->
Segmentation fault
```

It seems that clang++ and g++ 7.1.0 or later evaluates `tim->async_wait()` first.

g++ 6.3.0 evaluates `tim = std::move(tim)` first.

Is this an undefined behavior? Or evaluation order is defined at some point?

Comment: I currently don't have the standards wording, but I'm pretty sure this is undefined behaviour because you're `tim->async_wait` call acts on an object which has been moved from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The evaluation order in C++17 is well-defined, such that [the expression leading to the function call (`tim->async_wait`) is sequenced before any of its arguments](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.call#5).

C++14 however, this is unspecified, due to [lack of such sequencing rules](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.call#8). That is, it may work, it may not, and implementations aren't required to tell you which way it picks, or even to be consistent from one call to another.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That means if the compiler fully support C++17, `tim = std::move(tim)` is better choice. Because of shared count is not changed, it is higher performance (speed) than copy implementation. Is that right?

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo: Performance is kind of irrelevant in this context, since you're about to perform an asynchronous dispatch operation anyway. I doubt the atomic increment/decrements are going to be the difference maker in terms of performance.

Comment: You mean you think that atomic increment/decrement makes performance difference in general, but it is not a dominant factor in this case. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: It doesn't matter that `tim->async_wait` is sequenced before its arguments if it's a member function - it will still be called with the pre-move `this` pointer, after the `move` has already occurred.

Comment: @Eric: It's not about how it works if it is sequenced before. Indeed, it *needs* to be sequenced before to work. The problem is if it is sequenced *after*. After the arguments are evaluated, `tim` no longer has a valid pointer. So you have to fetch the pointer *before* evaluating the arguments, or the thing doesn't work.