# C++17 and asynchronous member functions calling with move capture lambda expression

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, move, asio

In [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57108220/timing-of-lambda-expression-move-capture) I've asked, I've learned some of evaluation orders are well defined since C++17. postfix-expression such as `a->f(...)`and `a.b(...)` are the part of them. See https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.call#5

In the [Boost.Asio](https://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html), the following style asynchronous member function call is typical patter.

```
auto sp_object = std::make_shared<object>(...);
sp_object->async_func(
    params,
    [sp_object]
    (boost::syste_error_code const&e, ...) {
        if (e) return;
        sp_object->other_async_func(
            params,
            [sp_object]
            (boost::syste_error_code const&e, ...) {
                if (e) return;
                // do some
            }
        );
    }
);
```

I'd like to clarify the following three cases's safety.

**Case1: shared_ptr move and member function**

```
auto sp_object = std::make_shared<object>(...);
sp_object->async_func(
    params,
    [sp_object = std::move(sp_object)]
    (boost::syste_error_code const&e, ...)  mutable { // mutable is for move
        if (e) return;
        sp_object->other_async_func(
            params,
            [sp_object = std::move(sp_object)]
            (boost::syste_error_code const&e, ...) {
                if (e) return;
                // do some
            }
        );
    }
);
```

This pattern is like https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html

I think it is safe because the postfix-expression `->` is evaluated before `sp_object = std::move(sp_object)`.

**Case2: value move and member function**

```
some_type object(...);
object.async_func(
    params,
    [object = std::move(object)]
    (boost::syste_error_code const&e, ...)  mutable { // mutable is for move
        if (e) return;
        object.other_async_func(
            params,
            [object = std::move(object)]
            (boost::syste_error_code const&e, ...) {
                if (e) return;
                // do some
            }
        );
    }
);
```

I think is is dangerous because even if the postfix-expression `.` is evaluated before `object = std::move(object)`, `async_func` may access the member of `object`.

**Case3: shared_ptr move and free function**

```
auto sp_object = std::make_shared<object>(...);
async_func(
    *sp_object,
    params,
    [sp_object = std::move(sp_object)]
    (boost::syste_error_code const&e, ...)  mutable { // mutable is for move
        if (e) return;
        other_async_func(
            *sp_object,
            params,
            [sp_object = std::move(sp_object)]
            (boost::syste_error_code const&e, ...) {
                if (e) return;
                // do some
            }
        );
    }
);
```

This pattern is like https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html

I think it is dangerous because there is no postfix-expression. So `sp_object` could be moved by third argument move capture before dereference as `*sp_object` by the first argument.

**conclusion**

Only case1 is safe and others are dangerous (undefined behavior).
I need to be careful that It is unsafe on C++14 and older compilers.
It can speed up **calling asynchronous member function** because shared_ptr's atomic counter operation is not happened. See [Why would I std::move an std::shared_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41871115/why-would-i-stdmove-an-stdshared-ptr)
But I also  need to consider that advantage could be ignored, it is depends on the application.

Am I understanding correctly about C++17 evaluation order change (precise definition) and asynchronous operation  relationship?

Comment: firstly, why do you think `Case:1` is safe? though `sp_object->async_func` evaluated before `sp_object = std::move(sp_object)`....whether it is undefined or not is totally depends on `async_func`'s definition, what do you think would happen when `async_func` access `shared_from_this()`?

Comment: Because `sp_object = std::move(sp_object)` keep the same pointee object. Moved to `sp_object.get()` returns the same address (object) of `this` is `async_func()`. So I believe that `shared_from_this()` works fine. Here is working example https://wandbox.org/permlink/NooUkn4SUSAOPLDU

Comment: in-case of moving shared_ptr this is what `std` do have to say "10) Move-constructs a shared_ptr from r. After the construction, `*this` contains a copy of the previous state of r, r is empty and its stored pointer is `null`. The template overload doesn't participate in overload resolution if Y* is not implicitly convertible to (until C++17)compatible with (since C++17) T*."....so not sure what you've been seeing is well-defined.

Comment: I think that https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.call#5 means at `sp_object->` is replaced to the address of `sp_object.get()`. Let's say the address is `addr_object`. So that means it is replaced as `addr_object->async_read`. After this replacing, `sp_object` become empty. But it is no problem.

Comment: Have changed your example a little bit ( as to me, it behaviour depends on what the function we invoke does ) https://wandbox.org/permlink/Tv9pbhvls2ZkHJE7 , let me know if I missed anything. got this "terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::bad_weak_ptr: bad_weak_ptr"

Comment: Good point! I am convinced. I understand that case1 is not always safe. As you mentioned, `shared_from_this()` is called after `handler` calling causes undefined behavior. I think that most of Boost.Asio API doesn't do that but my question is about general case. So case1 is not safe.The other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57108220/timing-of-lambda-expression-move-capture is safe but it depends on `boost::deadline_timer::async_wait()` definition. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: @Explorer_N what do you think the following case? Th class `object` doesn't inherit `std::enable_shared_from_this` including indirectly, and the class doesn't have the member `std::weak_ptr<object>` including indirectly. That means the class `object` doesn't expect the `this` in `async_func`is held by `std::shared_ptr`. If the class `object` satisfies the requirement, is case1 safe?

Comment: >"Th class object doesn't inherit" : it is always the class that inherits, what do you mean by "class object"?

........>" is case1 safe?" don't access what has been moved, that is the key. cases doesn't matter.

Comment: I mean "if case1's object doesn't inherit `std::enable_shared_from_this`". In other words, doesn't use `shared_from_this` mechanism. If that constraint is added, is case1 safe? I guess it is safe because `this` ptr is never moved.

Comment: >"I guess it is safe because this ptr is never moved": would be (I am +ve).

Comment: What does "would be (I am +ve)." mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer

Thanks to Explorer_N 's comments. I got the answer.

I asked that "Case1 is safe but Case2 and Case3 are unsafe is that rgiht?". However, Case1 is safe **if and only if a constraint I wrote later (*1) is satisfied**. That means **Case1 is unsafe in general**.

It is depends on `async_func()`

Here is an unsafe case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

struct object : std::enable_shared_from_this<object> {
    object(boost::asio::io_context& ioc):ioc(ioc) {
        std::cout << "object constructor this: " << this << std::endl;
    }

    template <typename Handler>
    void async_func(Handler&& h) {
        std::cout << "this in async_func: " << this << std::endl;
        h(123); // how about here?
        std::cout << "call shared_from_this in async_func: " << this << std::endl;
        auto sp = shared_from_this();
        std::cout << "sp->get() in async_func: " << sp.get() << std::endl;
    }

    template <typename Handler>
    void other_async_func(Handler&& h) {
        std::cout << "this in other_async_func: " << this << std::endl;
        h(123); // how about here?
        std::cout << "call shared_from_this in other_async_func: " << this << std::endl;
        auto sp = shared_from_this();
        std::cout << "sp->get() in other_async_func: " << sp.get() << std::endl;
    }

    boost::asio::io_context& ioc;
};

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;
    auto sp_object = std::make_shared<object>(ioc);

    sp_object->async_func(
        [sp_object = std::move(sp_object)]
        (int v) mutable { // mutable is for move
            std::cout << v << std::endl;
            sp_object->other_async_func(
                [sp_object = std::move(sp_object)]
                (int v) {
                    std::cout << v << std::endl;
                }
            );
        }
    );
    ioc.run();
}
```

Running demo https://wandbox.org/permlink/uk74ACox5EEvt14o

I considered why the first `shared_from_this()` is ok but second call throws `std::bad_weak_ptr` in the code above. That is because the callback handler is called from the `async_func` and `other_async_func` directly. The move happens twice. So that the first level (`async_func`) `shared_from_this` is failed.

Even if the callback handler is NOT called from async function directly, it is still unsafe on multi-threaded case.

Here is an unsafe code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

struct object : std::enable_shared_from_this<object> {
    object(boost::asio::io_context& ioc):ioc(ioc) {
        std::cout << "object constructor this: " << this << std::endl;
    }

    template <typename Handler>
    void async_func(Handler&& h) {
        std::cout << "this in async_func: " << this << std::endl;

        ioc.post(
            [this, h = std::forward<Handler>(h)] () mutable {
                h(123);
                sleep(1);
                auto sp = shared_from_this();
                std::cout << "sp->get() in async_func: " << sp.get() << std::endl;
            }
        );
    }

    template <typename Handler>
    void other_async_func(Handler&& h) {
        std::cout << "this in other_async_func: " << this << std::endl;

        ioc.post(
            [this, h = std::forward<Handler>(h)] () {
                h(456);
                auto sp = shared_from_this();
                std::cout << "sp->get() in other_async_func: " << sp.get() << std::endl;
            }
        );
    }

    boost::asio::io_context& ioc;
};

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;
    auto sp_object = std::make_shared<object>(ioc);

    sp_object->async_func(
        [sp_object = std::move(sp_object)]
        (int v) mutable { // mutable is for move
            std::cout << v << std::endl;
            sp_object->other_async_func(
                [sp_object = std::move(sp_object)]
                (int v) {
                    std::cout << v << std::endl;
                }
            );
        }
    );
    std::vector<std::thread> ths;
    ths.reserve(2);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != 2; ++i) {
        ths.emplace_back(
            [&ioc] {
                ioc.run();
            }
        );
    }
    for (auto& t : ths) t.join();
}
```

Running Demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/xjLZWoLdn8xL89QJ

## Constraint of case1 is safe

*1
However, in the case1, if and only if `struct object` doesn't expect it is held by shared_ptr, it is safe. In other words, as long as `struct object`  doesn't use `shared_from_this` mechanism, it is safe.

## Another way to control the sequence. (C++14 supported)

If and only if the constraint above is satisfied, we can control the evaluation sequence without C++17 sequence definition.
It supports both case1 and case3. Simply get reference of the pointee object that is held by shared_ptr. The key point is pointee object is preserved even if the shared_ptr is moved. So get the reference of pointee object before the shared_ptr moved, and then shared_ptr is moved, the pointee object is not affected.

However, shared_from_this is exceptional case. It uses shared_ptr mechanism directly. So that is affected by shared_ptr moving. Hence it is unsafe. That is the reason of the constraint.

### Case1

```
// The class of sp_object class doesn't use shared_from_this mechanism
auto sp_object = std::make_shared<object>(...);
auto& r = *sp_object;
r.async_func(
    params,
    [sp_object]
    (boost::syste_error_code const&e, ...) {
        if (e) return;
        auto& r = *sp_object;
        r.other_async_func(
            params,
            [sp_object]
            (boost::syste_error_code const&e, ...) {
                if (e) return;
                // do some
            }
        );
    }
);
```

### Case3

```
// The class of sp_object class doesn't use shared_from_this mechanism
auto sp_object = std::make_shared<object>(...);
auto& r = *sp_object;
async_func(
    r,
    params,
    [sp_object = std::move(sp_object)]
    (boost::syste_error_code const&e, ...)  mutable { // mutable is for move
        if (e) return;
        auto& r = *sp_object;
        other_async_func(
            r,
            params,
            [sp_object = std::move(sp_object)]
            (boost::syste_error_code const&e, ...) {
                if (e) return;
                // do some
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be greatly simplified to  "is the following safe":

```
some_object.foo([bound_object = std::move(some_object)]() {
    bound_object.bar()
});
```

From your linked question, [the standard says](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.call#5)

> All side effects of argument evaluations are sequenced before the function is entered

One such side-effect is the `move` from some_object - so this is equivalent to:

```
auto callback = [bound_object = std::move(some_object)]() {
    bound_object.bar()
}
some_object.foo(std::move(callback));
```

Clearly, this moves out of `some_object` before the `foo` method is called. This is safe if and only if `foo` is called on a moved-from object.

---

Using this knowledge:

- Case 1 will likely segfault and is definitely not safe, because calling `operator->()` on a moved-from `shared_ptr` returns `nullptr`, which you then call `->async_func` on.
- Case 2 is safe only if calling `async_func` on a moved-from `some_type` is safe, but it's very unlikely it does what you intend unless the type doesn't actually define a move constructor.
- Case 3 is not safe because while it's ok to move a shared pointer after dereferencing it (as moving a shared pointer does not change the object it points to), C++ makes no guarantee about which function argument will be evaluated first.

Comment: Do you mean the first code and the second code are equivalent ?

Comment: Updated to explicitly cover your cases

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo you can accept this as an answer, it clearly states evaluation comes before execution and that to me sounds a key thing.

Comment: In your 1st example, `foo()` is called with moved from object. This is running code: https://wandbox.org/permlink/tDxm3LMiVyzAeT9J If `foo()` is not safe called with moved from object, it is unsafe. I agree this point. It is case2 of my question. In case1, some_object is `shared_ptr`. See https://wandbox.org/permlink/domM8hS1JvuxqUs0 If and only if some_class doesn't expect "I am held by shared_ptr", I think this is safe. I think that case1 with above constraint is safe. That is my point.

Comment: `some_object->foo(...)` is equivalent to `some_object.get()->foo(...)`.In C++17 `some_object.get()` is sequenced before `bount_object = std::move(some_object)`. That is my point.

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo: You're right, case 1 looks safe after all based on that reasoning

Comment: Updated: case 3 is also unsafe